# how to create a text file using Groovy in a buildflow [Jenkins]?

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-build-flow

I have a `Builflow` with `Groovy script`. I cannot seem to be able to create a new file. The command does execute but I cannot see the file in my `workspace`.

First to create it in WORKSPACE I need to know where it is.

```
def WORKSPACE= build.environment.get("WORKSPACE")
```

Then define and create the file

```
def inputFile = new File(WORKSPACE + "/propfile")
new File(WORKSPACE + "/propfile")
```

Comment: Have you written anything to it?  If you don't write anything to it, it's just a handle to a non-existent file, eg: `new File("${WORKSPACE}/propfile") << 'hello'`

Comment: thanks for the reply. I now do new File(WORKSPACE + "/propfile") << 'hello' which result in java.io.FileNotFoundException

Comment: So what does: `println new File("${WORKSPACE}/propfile").canonicalPath` show?  Does that look ok?

Comment: yep, if I copy the path, I can access it on the slave directly